# GridView, ViewHolder and Checkbox

Tags: android, gridview, checkbox

I used this [tutorial](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/) to create a `GridView` with `CheckBoxe`s. 
I added also a TextView and it's working well.

My Question:
How can I change the CheckState of the `CheckBox` by clicking on the `ImageView`?
I tried a lot but nothing helped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) v;

CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(img.getId());
```

Now I have the CheckBox object and can change the CheckState.